Grid row items not in level across columns
I have 5 columns and 5 rows.
4 of the columns have similar content but the second column content is smaller, due to this the "Heading" in second/fourth row is not in level across columns.
What i want?
I want each of the content across columns to be in level with each other.
Code snippet-


.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 12px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);;
}

.grid-column {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    height: 430px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 12px;
    display: grid;
grid-auto-rows:auto;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
</div>



What i tried?
I removed flex and used Grid according to below stackoverflow question but it did not work-
How to make flexbox items equal height and/or start at the same point

The markup for a grid is different from the markup for a table.
When you markup a table, there is an element for the <table> itself, an element for each row (<tr>), and an element for each cell (<td>).


<table>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>



When you markup a grid, all you have is an element for the grid itself, then an element for each grid item.


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>



If you want successive elements to fill column 1 first, followed by column 2, followed by column 3, you can use grid-auto-flow: column to achieve this. In this scenario, you need to specify the number of rows you want your grid to have, with grid-template-rows.


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>



In your HTML you have a <div class="grid-column"> to represent each column. This actually makes life more difficult if you want a two-dimensional layout where both your rows and columns are aligned. Your first option is to remove these column wrappers altogether. Your second option is to style them out of the DOM with display: contents. I have used this second technique in this snippet, which is based on your one:


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 12px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.grid-column {
  display: contents;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
</div>



Now you’re going to ask about column backgrounds. One way to achieve this using grid is by using backgrounds on your grid items and then controlling the gaps between them. Your column wrappers come in handy here: even though we can’t style them directly, we can style their descendant elements, including their :first-child and :last-child, in order to control things like the rounded corners.


body {
  margin: 12px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0 12px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.grid-column {
  display: contents;
}

.grid-column > * {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.grid-column > :first-child {
  padding-top: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.grid-column > :last-child {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-column">
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <div class="p">This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.This div contains a very long word.</div>
    <div>Heading</div>
    <di>1.List 2.List 3.List</di>
  </div>
</div>



